Error: Al abrir un archivo EXCEL elegido por combobox no lo puedo editar
Estoy utilizando este código para abrir un archivo Excel, utilizando un combobox que me guarda los archivos que tengo en una carpeta y con un boton los abro. El problema es que cuando los abro, no los puedo editar y no me deja escribir en las celdas, cuando lo cierro no se cierra y deja el archivo abierto. Se cierra el archivo que esta corriendo el VSB.
Private Sub BtnOpenFile_Click()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As String
    Dim fullPath As String

    ' Especifica la ruta de la carpeta donde están los archivos
    folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Matrices\alcance1\emisiones_fugitivas\"

    ' Obtiene el archivo seleccionado en el ComboBox
    selectedFile = ComboBox1.Value

    ' Verifica que se haya seleccionado un archivo
    If selectedFile <> "" Then
        ' Construye la ruta completa del archivo
        fullPath = folderPath & selectedFile
        ' Verifica si el archivo existe antes de abrirlo
        If Dir(fullPath) <> "" Then
            ' Abre el archivo seleccionado
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fullPath, ReadOnly:=False)
            ' Opcionalmente, puedes hacer más acciones con el libro abierto 'wb'
            ' Por ejemplo, puedes mostrar alguna información del archivo o realizar operaciones adicionales.
        Else
            MsgBox "El archivo seleccionado no se encontró en la carpeta.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Por favor, selecciona un archivo.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub


Creo que debes cerrar el archivo para guardar los cambios: wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

Pero ¿qué es lo que realmente quieres hacer? ¿Abrir el archivo y escribir en él de forma manual para luego cerrarlo con la macro? ¿Abrir el fichero, modificar celdas y luego grabarlo automáticamente?

Asegurate que el archivo que quieres abrir no está protegido (clic derecho en el archivo) y que tienes permisos sobre la carpeta que contiene los archivos
